# What is the time complexity of this particular method?

Tags: java, time-complexity

```
class Tower {
      public void moveDisks(int n, Tower Destination, Tower Buffer) {
         if (n > 0) {
            moveDisks(n-1, Buffer, Destination);
            moveTopto(Destination);
            Buffer.moveDisks(n-1, Destination, this);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code to the method I mentioned above. This is part of an algorithm that solves the classic Hanoi Tower problem. I just can't wrap my head around a time complexity for this as the it has quite a bit of recursion.

This is a method within the class `Tower`. `moveTopto` is `O(1)`, so shouldn't affect the runtime.

Comment: what is this statement `buffer,moveDisks(n-1, destination, this);` ?

Comment: The time complexity also depends on `moveTopto`. Include it for a better answer.

Comment: Could you please paste the complete code here so that we can better understand it?

Comment: Now you need to tell us what `buffer.moveDisks` is, what time complexity does that method have?

Comment: @CydrickT Can you delete your comments please, trying to clean up this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on the time complexity of the `moveTopto` and `buffer.moveTopto`.

Basically to compute the complexity you will have to add the up the times. The time for `n` will be the time for `n-1`, plus the time for `moveTopto` plus the time for `buffer.moveTopto` plus a constant. Now you see that it will have at least `O(N)`, but can have higher, especially if `buffer.moveTopto` have non-constant time complexity.

If you mean `Buffer.moveTopto` then the time would be about twice the time for `n-1`, that is you would have `t(n) = 2*t(n-1)+constant`. That gives `O(2^n)`.

Comment: The video was more helpful, but this is definitely the more valid answer!

Answer (score 1):

Good explanation of recursive algorithms complexity analysis
[Video Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZ0MP5euLQ0)

PS. If you're too lazy to open the link and understand and just want the answer - complexity ~ O(2 ^ n)

Comment: This video actually has everything I need. I wouldn't have thought people made a video about the run time of the Tower of Hanoi problem!